# D3js bar chart from external json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bar-chart

I have been looking around how to load data from json  to a bar chart, but I just can't get it to work.

I have a JSON file that looks like this (a part of it):

```
[{
    "id":1,
    "geslacht":"Vrouw",
    "totaal punten":60,
    "project 1":9,
    "ucd":6,
    "internetstandaarden":7,
    "understanding design":7,
    "Teamproject deel 1":6,
    "Taal in context":6,
    "Vormgeving":7,
    "Marketing":6,
    "Students in Motion":7,
    "Teamproject deel 2":7,
    "H&C":6,
    "Programmeren":7,
    "M&I":7,
    "Project 3":6,
    "Mediageschiedenis":6,
    "Business Mapping":7,
    "Plug & Play":7,
    "SLC":7,
    "Studieregie":8,
},{
    "id":2,
    "geslacht":"Man",
    "totaal punten":43,
    "project 1":8,
    "ucd":6,
    "internetstandaarden":0,
    "understanding design":7,
    "Teamproject deel 1":6,
    "Taal in context":0,
    "Vormgeving":7,
    "Marketing":7,
    "Students in Motion":7,
    "Teamproject deel 2":7,
    "H&C":6,
    "Programmeren":7,
    "M&I":0,
    "Project 3":6,
    "Mediageschiedenis":0,
    "Business Mapping":7,
    "Plug & Play":7,
    "SLC":8,
    "Studieregie":6,
}]
```

How can I create a bar chart of this?

Comment: Could you give some ideas of things you've tried and what success you've had - or any failures and specific errors

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a charting library such as [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com). It's really simple to use and offers a variety of different chart types. You would probably need to format the JSON file slightly differently though (I think - at first glance)